# Холодный кипяток

Tags: значение-слов

Читал в ЖЖ заметку с заголовком **"Сломай мозг иностранцу!"**. Там всякие забавные словосочетания. Часть, из приведённых ниже, здесь уже обсуждалась. Например:

• Старый новый год
• Детская пластмассовая железная дорога
• Незаконные бандформирования
• Туалетная вода
• Среднее ухо
• Сухое вино
• У пациента сильная слабость
• Истинная правда
• Да нет наверное
• Смертная казнь

Ну и т.п. Ссылку на источник, если нужно, дам.

Всё понял, кроме одного:
**"Холодный кипяток"**
Что это такое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кипечёная вода, которая уже успела остыть. Вода холодная, но не из под крана.

Comment: Спасибо. 

Ну надо же. Я думал, что кипяток -- это вода температурой около +100 градусов.

Оказывается ещё и просто кипячённая вода.

Answer (score 1):

У кипятка действительно два значения. 
И кипящая вода и вода **кипевшая**.
Так что тут все правильно. Кстати, в английском в этом значении "boiled water" никого не забавляет. Да и вообще, плохо автор этой подборки думает об иностранцах. Большинство этих выражений вполне корректны и уместны, многие имеют прямые аналоги в английском (думаю, не только там).
По-настоящему забавен, имхо, только "старый Новый год". Думаю, тут уместно с заглавной, ибо речь о празднике и это, кстати, тоже несколько понижает "уровень забавности". 
"Old New-York" Вас не смущает?!

Comment: >Old New-York" Вас не смущает?

Персонажи пародийного футуристического мультсериала "Футурама" живут в Новом Нью-Йорке (New New York, по-английски название города пишется  без дефиса), так что самими американцами это тоже воспринимается как оксюморон.

Comment: По-разному пишется. Не в этом дело.
А вот оксюморона не вижу.  
Old New(-)York - название старой части города, наверное есть и New New(-)York. Впрочем, я там не был. Новый Новгород - оксюморон?

Comment: Кипяток  это  кипящая  вода,  и  кипевшая,  но  не  остывшая.  Может  "холодный  кипяток"  это  и  метафора  какая-нибудь,  но  ощущается  как  неуклюжий  перевод,  калька.

Comment: Новый  Новгород,  как  название  новой  части  города  ( если  бы  это  потребовалось  и  прижилось ) - не  оксюморон.

Comment: >Кипяток это кипящая вода, и кипевшая, но не остывшая. Может "холодный кипяток" это и метафора какая-нибудь, но ощущается как неуклюжий перевод, калька.

А-а! Вот! Всё-таки **"не остывшая"**. 

Т.е. всё же есть ощущение *неуклюжести* выражения у читателя.

Или в каких-то краях всё же говорят "кипяток" и на холодную кипячённую воду?

Comment: @Nikolja, как минимум в Вологде, Твери, Мурманске и Санкт-Петербурге так сказать могут. Холодный кипяток - это не устойчивое словосочетание, но возникнуть вполне может. Из-за не очень хорошего качества воды из под крана, многие держат на кухне ёмкость с остывшим кипятком, вода в ней может быть как тёплой, так и холодной, если вода холодная, то и возникает словосочетание "холодный кипяток".

Comment: Большое спасибо за подробное объяснение!
Теперь я разобрался.

Comment: >Новый Новгород - оксюморон?

@behemothus, если и оксюморон, то слабый, так как то, что Новгород - это новый город, требует расшифровки. А вот, например, *новый Новый Уренгой* - это оксюморон, так два одинаковых слова, не омонимы, в русском языке употребляются для усиления (*синий-синий иней*), что в данном сочетании не соответствует истине.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то ничего необычного с физической точки зрения. На высокогорье и в барокамере вода кипит при невысокой температуре, и это конечно кипяток, хоть и не горячий.

А про холодный кипяток не слышал никогда. Слышал про остывший.Или остуженный.То есть это просто "кипяченая вода",холодная или горячая,- такое словосочетание устойчиво.

Comment: Правильно. Но и  остывший, и  остуженный  это  состояние  воды,  а  не  устойчивое  словосочетание.

Answer (score -1):

Ни даль ни ожогов ни ефремова не дает определение кипятка, как остывшей вскипевшей воды, только как кипящей или только что вскипевшей. Думаю это выдумка, тех кто использовал это слово не по назначению.

(Ни Даль, ни Ожегов, ни Ефремова не дают определения кипятка как остывшей вскипевшей воды, только — как кипящей или только что вскипевшей. Думаю, это выдумка тех, кто использовал это слово не по назначению.)

Comment: Вы не могли бы хотя бы видимость соблюдения правил производить? Я понимаю, опечатки, но авторов словарей с со строчной писать - это уже слишком.

Comment: А что касается кипятка - да, именно так понимали исходно. Кипяток - кипяченая вода. Не кипящая, а именно кипяченая.